# Ag Grid Column Grouping is not working with Infinite RowModalType

Tags: javascript, reactjs, ag-grid, ag-grid-react

I'm using "enterprise" version Ag-Grid with below config but the row grouping is not working and the column for which I've given rowGroup as true is not showing as Group.

```
<AgGridReact 
    rowSelection="multiple"
    groupSelectsChildren={true}
    groupDisplayType="singleColumn"
    rowModelType="infinite"
    autoGroupColumnDef={

      return {
    headerName: "Resource",
    fieldName:"Name",
    cellRenderer: 'agGroupCellRenderer'
}
    }
    onGridReady={params => {
        params.api.setDataSource("my data source here");
    }
/>
```

If I'm remove grouping, pagination with server side rendering is working fine.

Answer (score 1):

In the [official documentation page](https://www.ag-grid.com/react-data-grid/infinite-scrolling/), it is advised to use Server-Side Row Model over Infinite Row Model because it offers the same functionality with many more features.

They also suggest you to use Infinite Row Model if you want to display a large, flat **(not grouped)** list of data.

In the same [link](https://www.ag-grid.com/react-data-grid/row-models/), they also say: 'The Server-Side Row Model builds on the Infinite Row Model. In addition to lazy-loading the data as the user scrolls down, it also allows lazy-loading of grouped data with server-side grouping and aggregation.'

Furthermore

> Aggregation and grouping are not available in infinite scrolling. This is because to do so would require the grid knowing the entire dataset, which is not possible when using the Infinite Row Model. If you need aggregation and / or grouping for large datasets, check the Server-Side Row Model for doing aggregations on the server-side.

I see you have a group column, I'd use Server Side Row Model in this case.

Here's a specific example of grouping with pagination in SSRM you can take as a reference

```
'use strict';

import React, {
  useCallback,
  useMemo,
  useRef,
  useState,
  StrictMode,
} from 'react';
import { createRoot } from 'react-dom/client';
import { AgGridReact } from 'ag-grid-react';
import 'ag-grid-enterprise';
import 'ag-grid-community/styles/ag-grid.css';
import 'ag-grid-community/styles/ag-theme-alpine.css';


const getServerSideDatasource = (server) => {
  return {
    getRows: (params) => {
      console.log('[Datasource] - rows requested by grid: ', params.request);
      var response = server.getData(params.request);
      // adding delay to simulate real server call
      setTimeout(function () {
        if (response.success) {
          // call the success callback
          params.success({
            rowData: response.rows,
            rowCount: response.lastRow,
          });
        } else {
          // inform the grid request failed
          params.fail();
        }
      }, 200);
    },
  };
};

const GridExample = () => {
  const containerStyle = useMemo(() => ({ width: '100%', height: '100%' }), []);
  const gridStyle = useMemo(() => ({ height: '100%', width: '100%' }), []);

  const [columnDefs, setColumnDefs] = useState([
    { field: 'country', rowGroup: true, hide: true },
    { field: 'athlete', minWidth: 190 },
    { field: 'gold', aggFunc: 'sum' },
    { field: 'silver', aggFunc: 'sum' },
    { field: 'bronze', aggFunc: 'sum' },
  ]);
  const defaultColDef = useMemo(() => {
    return {
      flex: 1,
      minWidth: 90,
      resizable: true,
      sortable: true,
    };
  }, []);
  const autoGroupColumnDef = useMemo(() => {
    return {
      flex: 1,
      minWidth: 180,
    };
  }, []);

  const onGridReady = useCallback((params) => {
    fetch('https://www.ag-grid.com/example-assets/olympic-winners.json')
      .then((resp) => resp.json())
      .then((data) => {
        // setup the fake server with entire dataset
        var fakeServer = new FakeServer(data);
        // create datasource with a reference to the fake server
        var datasource = getServerSideDatasource(fakeServer);
        // register the datasource with the grid
        params.api.setServerSideDatasource(datasource);
      });
  }, []);

  return (
    <div style={containerStyle}>
      <div style={gridStyle} className="ag-theme-alpine-dark">
        <AgGridReact
          columnDefs={columnDefs}
          defaultColDef={defaultColDef}
          autoGroupColumnDef={autoGroupColumnDef}
          rowModelType={'serverSide'}
          pagination={true}
          paginationAutoPageSize={true}
          suppressAggFuncInHeader={true}
          animateRows={true}
          onGridReady={onGridReady}
        />
      </div>
    </div>
  );
};

const root = createRoot(document.getElementById('root'));
root.render(
  <StrictMode>
    <GridExample />
  </StrictMode>
);
```

Plunker: https://plnkr.co/edit/dyKXE6lXT3vJa60p?preview